# Multiple axes labels in R

Tags: r, plot, axis, axis-labels, multiple-axes

I have a 3 columned data set. The third column is "string" values (i.e. names) while 1st and 2nd are corresponding name's values in 2 of the corresponding fields. I would like to plot a conventional graph between 1st and 2nd column, but then in the top side of the plot (i.e. side=3 in R) I would like to add the corresponding names to the corresponding points in the graph. How to do ?

Say I have a data set like :

```
A  B  C 
1  10 ABC
2  20 DEF
```

and plotting A vs B with C in the top (side=3) labelled to the corresponding point. An example plot is shown here

[image]

Comment: You need to post data and code. It's also rather unclear that your requests to "plot a conventional graph between 1st and 2nd column" and "plotting A vs B with C in the top" actually mean. Might be necessary to mock up an example in ImageMagick or GIMP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [axes labels for 3 variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940163/axes-labels-for-3-variables)

Answer (score 0):

**This is the solution **

```
    plot(cc$z[1:10],cc$y[1:10],col=2,pch=20,las=1,xlab="Redshift",ylab=expression(paste(mu)))
     axis(3, at=cc$z[1:10], labels=cc$name[1:10],las=2,cex.axis=0.5)
```